# Grouping mediaPlayer together

Tags: android, media-player

For example I have several mediaPlayer objects for different sounds. How would I group them together and check whether any of them are playing at any one time and stopping them all? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct method for that  `myPlayer.isPlaying()`